# ODBC-JDBC Bridge Windows-1251 (Cyrillic) character encoding

Tags: jdbc, character-encoding, odbc, dbase, cyrillic

I've got a dbase file with window 1251 encoding. I've made an ODBC datasource for this file and I would like to access it with JDBC-ODBC bridge from java with the following code:

```
PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(System.out, true, "UTF-8");
System.out.println("TEST: Русский язык");
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.put("charSet", "windows-1251");
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:odbc:test_ds",properties);
Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
String sql = "SELECT * FROM table";
ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);

while (resultSet.next()) {            
        System.out.println(resultSet.getString("DESC"));
}
```

Character encoding is OK for test println (2nd line), but encoding for data from dbase is incorrect.

I'm able to open dbf file with LibreOffice with the same encoding where everything is correct.

Is there  any chance to set encoding correctly?

Is it possible to set connection encoding in the connection string?

EDIT: After further investigation, I think the problem is ODBC related. I tried to open the defined datasource with Excel and the encoding was wrong. (I had no chance to set encoding either for odbc connection, neither for Excel connection)

Answer (score 0):

This works for me on cyrillic characters:

```
properties.put("charSet", "Cp1251");
```